# Extend range in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I need a loop containing `range(3,666,2)` and 2 (for the sieve of Eratosthenes, by the way). This doesn't work ("AttributeError: 'range' object has no attribute 'extend'" ... or "append"):

```
primes = range(3,limit,2)
primes.extend(2)
```

How can I do it in the simple intuitive pythonesque way?

Comment: Please print out your expected o/p.

Comment: @python-coder: Python 3: `AttributeError: 'range' object has no attribute 'extend'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`range()` in Python 3 returns a dedicated *immutable* sequence object. You'll have to turn it into a list to extend it:

```
primes = list(range(3, limit, 2))
primes.append(2)
```

Note that I used `list.append()`, not `list.extend()` (which expects a *sequence* of values, not one integer).

However, you probably want to **start** your loop with `2`, not end it. Moreover, materializing the whole range into a list requires some memory and kills the efficiency of the object. Use iterator chaining instead:

```
from itertools import chain

primes = chain([2], range(3, limit, 2))
```

Now you can loop over `primes` without materializing a whole list in memory, and still include `2` at the start of the loop.

Comment: And if I have `range(3,ThisIsSuchABigNumber,2)` ? Will I do a list of billions just for a range?

Comment: @Liviu: exactly, which is why you would not want to do that, really.

Comment: @Liviu `chain` and `range` are lazy functions. `chain` will lazily loop over its arguments. So, the entire list will not be created in memory, when invoked. `range` will return a `range` object, not the entire list.

Comment: When I asked the question, the `chain` solution wasn't added yet. Now it's hard to choose an answer.

Comment: @Liviu: That's up to you. :-) I was trying to first address why `.extend()` doesn't work on a `range()` object (assuming you tried to use `list` methods on it), before showing how it should be done instead. Jon focused on the latter first. Such is the nature of Stack Overflow sometimes, if the answer is reasonably obvious for the regulars, it comes down to the faster typer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree this is certainly the more thorough answer addressing all concerns :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're only looping and don't want to materialise, then:

```
from itertools import chain
primes = chain([2], range(3, limit, 2))
```

I think the two makes more sense at the start though...